# Can't solve Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

Tags: java, android, apache, android-studio, deprecated

I'm following a tutorial it worked smoothly at first but some deprecated problems got in. I'm new in programming and I tried some of the solutions that i've read but none of them worked on to solve this problem. I also tried to pasting some code on org.apache.http.legacy which is located on C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\optional..  BUT i dont know how to open that file so i tried opening it using notepad++.... the code look like this..

```
 [
  {
    "name": "org.apache.http.legacy",
    "jar": "org.apache.http.legacy.jar",
    "manifest": false
  }
]
```

I also tred adding an extension filename on the ***useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'*** .. like ***useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy.jar'***
but nothing happened..

And Also changing different classpath like..

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

Even changin the

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

And a lot of stuff trying paste, change, delete, cut and replace having some sort of trial and error.. this stuff i made was n a comment because i'm having a rial and error on them..

```
//    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')


///////////////
//compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+'
//
//compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'
//
//compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+'
//
//compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}


//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//
//android {
//         compileSdkVersion 23
//      buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
//
//    defaultConfig {
//        applicationId "com.example.--------.-----------"
//        minSdkVersion 19
//        targetSdkVersion 23
//    }
//    buildTypes {
//        release {
//            minifyEnabled false
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),             'proguard-rules.pro'
//        }
//    }
//
//}
//
//dependencies {
//
//    compile project(':comtaxibulgariamap_mapsforge_044201406271417533')
//    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//}
```

[build.gradle(Module:app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07uqD.png)

[build.gradle(MyProjectName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PObWX.png)

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, its working fine for me

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "calib.inspectionpro.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.0.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

}

Comment: The getDefaultProguardFile said cannot resolve the symbol.. And it has still the message Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy It also highlighted this part-- compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'... do you have any advice or suggestion? btw thanks for the your response..

Comment: Sorry I didn't find any solution.But I made a sample example with above code didn't get any error. Just have a look on this. https://www.dropbox.com/s/py0w6pbrkych1tb/SamplePro_Gradle.zip?dl=0